# Search for sqlservr.exe while adding firewall rule via netsh command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've created a bath file to add firewall rules for sql server... here is a part of the script

```
set PROGRAM="%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.DBSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"
set RULE_NAME="SQL Server"
echo Checking firewall rule %RULE_NAME%.
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%RULE_NAME% >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Rule %RULENAME% already exist.
) else (
    echo Rule %RULENAME% not exist. Creating...
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=in action=allow program=%PROGRAM%
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=out action=allow program=%PROGRAM%
)
```

I am talking about the first line

```
set PROGRAM="%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.DBSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"
```

Is there any way I can locate the file without typing the path? as The file sqlservr.exe is located differently in different OS and dependent upon the instance name...

Comment: I don't have SQL DB-server so here's the general hint: run regedit, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` and under that key look for the DBserver-related keys where the path of `bin` directory is present. Then you can use `reg query` and `for /f` parsing to get that path in the batch file (I or someone else will provide an example once you find that key/value).

Comment: You could simply parse the output of `dir /S` (recursive search) with a `for /F` loop; however, it might last some time, depending on the start (root) search directory...

Comment: `where /R "%ProgramFiles%" sqlservr.exe` returns two paths for me (`110` and `120`)  so should be a separate rule for each one?

Comment: Uhm guys, and what if sql server is installed on `d:\sqlserver`?

Comment: `wmic path Win32_Service where "pathname like '%%sqlservr.exe%%'" get PathName|find /I "sqlservr.exe"`

Comment: Thanks guys... I'll be looking into the suggestions. @wOxxOm ... to simplify the things, let us stick to these assumptions: 1) Only one instance of SQL Server is installed (2) SQL Server is installed to its default location.

Comment: @JosefZ .. Your solution looks very good. I created a batch file and placed this command. When I execute the file, it shows this at the cmd terminal. >"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DEVSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sDEVSERVER.. How can I store this to a variable. I tried set PROGRAM=... but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ss=sqlservr.exe"
rem set "ss=GoogleUpdate.exe"    my testing value
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('
    wmic Service where "pathname like '%%%ss%%%'" get PathName/value^|find /I "%ss%"
') do (
  @rem echo debugging G "%%~G"
  for /F delims^=^" %%x in ("%%G") do (
    set "_program=%%~x"
    @rem echo debugging x "%%~x"
  )
)
rem next two lines merely for debugging to check up results
set _program
echo "%_program%"
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `PathName` value;
- `%%x` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

Note the `delims^=^"` trick to treat a double quote character as a delimiter.